# Java. Trouble defining a method

Tags: java, methods, import, package, subclass

I have the class Mappa which has a method of the same name which creates two matrix

```
package mappa.product;

import mappa.Settore;

public class Mappa {
    private Name mappaName;
    private final Settore [][] settore;
    private int Matrice [][];
    private static final int X=23;
    private static final int Y=14;
    public Mappa (){
        settore = new Settore[X][Y];
        for (int i=0; i < X; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<Y; j++) {
                settore[i][j] = new Settore (i,j);
            }
        }
        Matrice = new int[23][14];
    }



    public int[][] getMatrice() {
        return Matrice;
    }

    public void setMatrice(int matrice[][]) {
        Matrice = matrice;
    }

    public Name getMappaName() {
        return mappaName;
    }

    public void setMappaName(Name mappaName) {
        this.mappaName = mappaName;
    }
    public Settore[][] getSettori(){
        return settore;
    }
    public void addSettori(){
        Settore.add(settore);
    }


}
```

then i have the class MappaCreator (which is in another package) and the mainly function of this class is to recall the method mappa() of the class Mappa, when i write directly inside the class like this there is no problem

```
package mappa.creator;
import mappa.product.*;
public class MappaCreator {
    Mappa mappa = new Mappa();  
        public MappaCreator(){
            }     
}
package mappa.creator;

import mappa.product.*;

public class MappaFermiCreator extends MappaCreator {

    public MappaFermiCreator() {
        Mappa mappa = new MappaFermi();
        this.mappa=mappa;
    }


}
```

but when i write it inside the method MappaCreator() i get the warning the "value of the local variable is not used" and the error "mappa cannot be resolved or is not a field" in the method MappaFermiCreator() of the subclass MappaFermiCreator

```
package mappa.creator;
import mappa.product.*;
public class MappaCreator {
        public MappaCreator(){
            Mappa mappa = new Mappa();//The value of the local variable is not used
        }
}
package mappa.creator;

import mappa.product.*;

public class MappaFermiCreator extends MappaCreator {

    public MappaFermiCreator() {
        Mappa mappa = new MappaFermi();
        this.mappa=mappa;//mappa cannot be resolved or is not a field
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `MappaCreator` nor its subclass `MappaFermiCreator` has an instance variable `mappa` so it doesn't compile. Add this to the superclass `MappaCreator`

`protected Mappa mappa;`

or add this to `MappaFermiCreator`

`private Mappa mappa;`

Answer (score 0):

```
public MappaCreator(){
            Mappa mappa = new Mappa();//The value of the local variable is not used
        }
```

`mappa` is a local variable in this method (the constructor) and as this is the only line, the variable is never used

---

```
public MappaFermiCreator() {
        Mappa mappa = new MappaFermi();
        this.mappa=mappa;//mappa cannot be resolved or is not a field
    }
```

`this.mappa`  is never declared and therefore cannot be resolved.

---

You should not duplicate the logic of the super class in the sub class. One way to avoid this is to employ `super()` in order to use the functionality that is defined in the super class.

```
public class MappaCreator 
{
    private Mappa mappa;

    public MappaCreator(Mappa mappa)
    {
            this.mappa = mappa;
    }

    public MappaCreator()
    {
            this(new Mappa());
    }
}


public class MappaFermiCreator extends MappaCreator 
{
    public MappaFermiCreator() 
    {
        super(new MappaFermi());
    }
}
```

This assumes that `MappaFermi extends Mappa`.